# Сократить множественное присвоение атрибутов объекту

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

При работе с ORM Laravel столкнулся с необходимостью добавить новую запись в таблицу посредством присвоения объекту всех нужных данных. Получилось следующее:

```
            $article = new Articles;
            $article->title = $request->input("title");
            $article->link = $request->input("link");
            $article->rubric = $request->input("rubric");
            $article->section = $request->input("section");
            $article->description = $request->input("description");
            $article->keywords = $request->input("keywords");
            $article->text = $request->input("text");
            $article->functions = $request->input("functions");
            $article->sort = $request->input("sort");
            $article->public = $request->input("public", 0);
            $article->save();
```

Можно ли как-то сократить весь этот список, или написать его более лаконично?

Answer (score 0):

> *Можно ли как-то сократить весь этот список, или написать его более лаконично?*

Т.к. имена свойств и аргументов у вас совпадают - можно собрать массив, и обработать его в цикле, примерно так:

```
$args = ["title", "link", "rubric", "section", "description", "keywords", "text", "functions", "sort", "public"];

$article = new Articles;

foreach ($args as $arg) {
    if ($arg == 'public') {
        $article->$arg = $request->input($arg, 0);
    } else {
        $article->$arg = $request->input($arg);
    }
}

$article->save();
```